# Accordion menu parent item goes to hyperlink instead of expanding

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I'm using a jQuery script to produce an accordion menu. It works great, unless a parent element has a hyperlink, in which case clicking it takes the user to the hyperlink instead of expanding the menu to display child elements. Any ideas how to fix the code below to resolve this issue?

**jQuery script:**

```
$( document ).ready( function( ) {
        $( '.menu li' ).each( function() {
                if( $( this ).children( 'ul' ).length > 0 ) {
                        $( this ).addClass( 'parent' );     
                }
        });

        $( '.menu li.parent > a' ).click( function( ) {
                $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'active' );
                $( this ).parent().children( 'ul' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
        });

        $( '#all' ).click( function() {

            $( '.menu li' ).each( function() {
                $( this ).toggleClass( 'active' );
                $( this ).children( 'ul' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
            });
        });

});
```

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Menu item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Menu item 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a>Menu item 1.2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Menu item 1.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a>Menu item 1.2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a>Menu item 1.2.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Menu item 1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.menu ul 
    {
        list-style: none outside none;
    }

.menu li a 
    {
        line-height: 25px;
    }

.menu > ul > li > a 
    {
        color: #3B4C56;
        display: block;
        font-weight: normal;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.menu li.parent > a 
    {
        padding: 0 0 0 28px;
    }

.menu li.parent > a:before 
    {
        background-image: url("../images/plus_minus_icons.png");
        background-position: 25px center;
         content: ""; 
        display: block;
        height: 21px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 23px;
    }

.menu ul li.active > a:before 
    {
        background-position: 0 center;
    }

.menu ul li ul 
    {
        border-left: 1px solid #D9DADB;
        display: none;
        margin: 0 0 0 12px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    }

.menu ul li ul li 
    {
        position: relative;
    }

.menu ul li ul li:before 
    {
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #E2E2E3;
        content: "";
        left: -20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        width: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link never should be clickable you can try somethin like that:

```
$( '.menu li.parent > a' ).click( function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault(); //this prevent the Link from redirecting
      $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'active' );
      $( this ).parent().children( 'ul' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
 });
```

if the redirect should still working, add

```
window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
```

after you expanded the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()` in your click events.

From the docs:

> For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is prevent the default action of the anchor to be triggered by using event.preventDefault().

```
$( '.menu li.parent > a' ).click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).parent().children( 'ul' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
});
```